# How to enable User Interaction on Disclosure Indicator, but not on UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with Static cells.  I want some off the cells to have a disclosure indicator that segues to another view.

The issue is that if the user inadvertently clicks the body of the cell, rather than the disclosure indicator, the cell changes color (grey), and remains so.

Is it possible to disable user interaction on the cell but not the disclosure?

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let identifier = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.reuseIdentifier as! String
            selectedCellIdentifier = identifier

            switch identifier {
            case "DescriptionCell":
performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowHelpView", sender: indexPath)
...
}
```

I can't call tableView.didDeselect because if the user successfully clicks the next disclosure, the first cell remains selected (grey color).

Comment: You want to change the color if the user tap on disclosure? If not, you can set the selection color to none (in Interface Builder or with code).

Comment: Thanks Larme.  Selection color to none will work perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the selection type of the cell to `None` in the xib or storyboard. Or in the `cellForRowAt:` you can set it to `.none`. This will prevent the grey selection state.

If you do not implement the didSelectRow delegate method then there will be no interaction for the cell.

Comment: Thanks Chris!  Will accept your answer as soon as they let me.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could just set `cell.selectionStyle = .none` in `cellForRow:At:`.